# pyinstaller error

Tags: windows, cmd

```
D:\TDDOWNLOAD\WWW1\pyinstaller>python Makespec.py C:\Documents and Settings\Admi
nistrator\桌面\a.py
wrote D:\TDDOWNLOAD\WWW1\pyinstaller\Documents\Documents.spec
now run Build.py to build the executable

D:\TDDOWNLOAD\WWW1\pyinstaller>python Build.py D:\TDDOWNLOAD\WWW1\pyinstaller\Do
cuments\Documents.spec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Build.py", line 1158, in <module>
    main(args[0], configfilename=opts.configfile)
  File "Build.py", line 1146, in main
    build(specfile)
  File "Build.py", line 1109, in build
    execfile(spec)
  File "D:\TDDOWNLOAD\WWW1\pyinstaller\Documents\Documents.spec", line 3, in <mo
dule>
    pathex=['D:\\TDDOWNLOAD\\WWW1\\pyinstaller'])
  File "Build.py", line 232, in __init__
    raise ValueError, "script '%s' not found" % script
ValueError: script 'C:\Documents' not found

D:\TDDOWNLOAD\WWW1\pyinstaller>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use full dir

```
cd D:\TDDOWNLOAD\WWW1\pyinstaller

python Makespec.py D:\TDDOWNLOAD\WWW1\pyinstaller\ss\a.py
python Build.py D:\TDDOWNLOAD\WWW1\pyinstaller\a\a.spec
```

it's ok

Answer (score 4):

put quotes around the paths with spaces

```
python Makespec.py "C:\Documents and Settings\Admi nistrator\桌面\a.py"
```